# Android - How to animate constraint layout params?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

i have layout like the following:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

...

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".5"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/glow">

        </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How i can animate app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias param?

i tried:

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        animation.start();
        animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator updatedAnimation) {

                float animatedValue = (float)updatedAnimation.getAnimatedValue();

                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams constraintLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mAvatarWrapper.getLayoutParams();
                constraintLayoutParams.horizontalBias = animatedValue;

            }
        });
```

or :

```
 public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
        View view;
        float horizontalBias;
        public ResizeAnimation(View view, float horizontalBias) {
            this.view = view;
            this.horizontalBias = horizontalBias;
        }

        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()).horizontalBias = (horizontalBias * interpolatedTime);
            view.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
            super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    ResizeAnimation resizeAnimation = new ResizeAnimation(
                mAvatarWrapper,1.0f

    );
    resizeAnimation.setDuration(1000);
    mAvatarWrapper.startAnimation(resizeAnimation);
```

without any success. Can someone refer me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope, it might help you.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams constraintLayoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) mAvatarWrapper.getLayoutParams();
constraintLayoutParams.horizontalBias = animatedValue;
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
mAvatarWrapper.setLayoutParams(constraintLayoutParams);
```

Comment: Where's the animation here?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `TransitionManager`.

```
  TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
  mAvatarWrapper.layoutParams = newParams
```

Also works for changing margins etc.